# Counting Shapes

Tags: vba, excel

What I'm trying to do here is give all the shapes in the worksheet a number.
The number must be counted up by one for each shape
So it should look something like this.

Keep in mind that these shapes are dynamic (it isn't always 2 columns, 3 rows)

[image: Showcase]

This is the code i tried, but doesn't seem to work

```
Sub Nummer()

Dim lngShapes As Long
lngShapes = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count

For teller = 1 To lngShapes
ActiveSheet.Shapes(teller).Value = teller
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The picture was just an example of how it should look, if i run the code it gives me the error "438" referring to the line "ActiveSheet.Shapes(teller).Value = teller".

Answer (score 1):

You get `Error 438` when trying to set the value (text) within the shape because the shapes collection does not have a `Value` property to set. You need to use `.TextFrame.Characters.Text`

If you change the line

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(teller).Value = teller
```

to

```
 ActiveSheet.Shapes(teller).TextFrame.Characters.Text = teller
```

your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the question is actually "Loop through all of the shapes in a sheet". Something like the following should be used:

```
Sub nameTheShapes()
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes
        shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = shp.ID
    Next
End Sub
```

Here we declare a `shape` as variable name `shp`. Then we loop through all of the `shapes` in the `sheet1`. Then we write the shape's `id` into the shape's `textframe2`.

If you have some charts hanging out on the same page, then you probably don't want to include them, so you can test the `shp.type` property to see that it's not a chart:

```
Sub nameTheShapes()
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes
        If shp.type = 1 Then
            shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = shp.ID
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: When I try to use this code I get "Run-time error ‘-2147024809 (80070057)’". Apparently you get this error if applied to a shape that cannot contain text. I use this code to add a shape maybe you know how to fix this? "ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, ActiveCell.Left, ActiveCell.Top, 100, 40).Select"

Comment: If it's always always going to be a rectangle always, you could change that `if` statement to `if shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle then`